# flutter native platform view

Tags: android, ios, flutter, native

please I want to know how exactly flutter native platform view works. does the platform view get recreated every time the build method is called and how do I kill or remove a platform view or unregister it to release resources

Comment: It seems like a lot of questions together. Please try to be specific and try to do some research yourself so you can write a detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to know really depends upon what Flutter does internally.

When you call setState in the Widget which displays a native view, it should cause the build method to be called again. Does that mean the native view is rebuilt? Probably not. [Flutter attempts to reuse the RenderObjects which are already in use.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs)

Regarding native view lifecycles, have you read the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views) from Flutter?

I peeked through the examples and I don't think you have to explicitly call dispose on native views, but I think you'll likely have to dispose any controllers you might need to interact with them (in the same manner you have to dispose of WebViewController if you use WebView).